# Converter with Combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I have a class, `address`:

```
public partial class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CountryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CityId { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsDefault { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

Each row needs different values for a *Cities* combo box. For example, one row needs "Paris, Marseille", the second needs "Abu Dhabi, Dubai, Sharjah", and the third needs "London, Nottingham".

How can I use a converter with a combobox inside the grid to show cities in that combobox based on selected country in another combobox inside the grid and display CityName
where I have an array of city Class which contains Name Property in the converter?

I need to know the syntax. How can I use the countryID to pass it to the converter to get a list of cities and binding it to CityCombobox in a datagrid and on changing the Country this list is updated according to the selected country?

Answer (score 0):

Create another property which represents the Country and City collection.

```
public partial class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries{get;set;}
    public Nullable<int> CountryId { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities{get;set;}
    public Nullable<int> CityId { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsDefault { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have two collection, which represents Countries and Cities.

```
<DataTemplate>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" SelectedItem = "{Binding CountryId}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Place all your controls here. The Countries represents the entire collection while the selectedItem represents the single item.

You can use INotifyProperty to implement propertychanged notification for your CountryId so that you can populate Cities accordingly.

edit

You need to have a collection of Address and pass that collection to the ItemsSource of the Grid.

```
ObservableCollection<Address> = new ObservableCollection<Address>();
//Load Addresses for each entity
//and show it as ItemsSource of the Grid.
```

The single row will represent the single Address object.

Comment: i have done this but i found that all rows are binded to the same city observablecollection so on filtring with selected country all combobox are filtered to the selected country and that is wrong,i have searched and i found that converter might help me but i dont know how to use it in my case

Comment: i mean ur answer will work if the two comboboxs are not in the grid but inside the grid it doesnt work correct as i need to make each combobox of city in each row binded to a different list of cities depends on the selectedCountry on the same row

Comment: Yes, actually I think you are passing the same Collection for Cities and Countries to every object. When you filter the Cities for a particular country, pass that collection only to the collection. By the way the actual object which represents the unique row of the Grid should be a collection as well...

Answer (score 0):

Create a viewmodel with both sets of data, that is:

```
class Country_CityViewModel
{
    public CountriesListModel { get; set; }
    public CitiesListModel { get; set; }

    public Country-CityViewModel()
    {
        CountriestListModel = new CountriestListModel ;
        CitiesListModel = new CitiesListModel ();
    }
}
```

Assign viewmodel by binding or code behind.

Assuming you assigned data to the page and give the page an x:name of CountryDetailsPage:

```
<ComboBox x:name:"CountryDetails"
          DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=CountryDetailsPage}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CountriesListModel.Countries}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Country"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Country.id, , Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="id" />

<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=CountryDetails}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem Source=CountryDetails}"
          DisplayMemberPath="City"
          SelectedValue="{Binding CitiesListModel.id, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="CountriesListModel.id" />
```

This mashed my head up a bit ... but try this logic. I think it will work.